# Apprtc not working in public network iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, webrtc, apprtc

I am using  [Apprtc](https://github.com/ISBX/apprtc-ios/) library for the real-time connection.
this is my server host URL @"https://appr.tc". Connection successfully established to any network, but in the **audio/video** sense

- audio/video only works on same/private network iOS to iOS or iOS to Android

  in public network audio/video only work in iOS to Android , Not working iOS
  device to iOS device .

do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** You need to bring up a TURN server, and configure the client with the addresses of your TURN server.

---

WebRTC attempts to connect two peers directly, but that's not always possible in all network configurations (e.g. when both sides are behind a NAT or a Firewall). In these cases, **WebRTC will fallback to using a TURN server**. It's basically a server that both peers can connect to, and it forwards packets from one to the other.

Comment: many thanks for reply. There is some confusion.
1. In public network iOS to Andriod working fine , but why iOS to iOS device not working? as far as your answer if firewall cause then iOS to Andriod also should not work , but its working here, do you have any idea about this @Saeed Jahed